# Value of sectionNameKeyPath for many-to-many relationship in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a Core Data model with three entities: `Notification`, `Group` and `Customer`. These are the relationships between them:

- A customer belongs to many groups and a group can have many customers.
- A notification is sent (belongs) to a group and a group can receive (have) many notifications.

I would like to show all notifications in a `UITableView` grouped by customer. I have created a `NSFetchedResultsController` like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 10;
fetchRequest.predicate = nil;

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notification"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entity;

// Default sort descriptors are built in a separate custom method
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [self getDefaultSortDescriptorsForEntity:entity];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;

return [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                           managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                    sectionNameKeyPath:@"group.customers.firstName"
                             cacheName:nil];
```

Assuming this is a valid way to retrieve all notifications grouped by customer (I'm not sure about that either) iOS is throwing the following exception:

```
@"Failed to fetch all Notification objects"
@"Reason: Invalid to many relationship in setPropertiesToFetch: (group.customers.firstName) (NSInvalidArgumentException)"
```

I have reviewed the relationships again and again to see if something is missing and everything seem to be correct. I can create and delete objects for all entities and links between them are correct as well.

My question is: Is it possible to traverse through several relationships in a `sectionNameKeyPath` value? How should many-to-many relationships be handled in this kind of scenario?

Comment: A "notification" can belong to more than one "customer". Do you want to display the notification in each "customer" section it belongs to?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, in this particular application it's OK to have the same notification repeated in several sections.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with a fetched results controller, because a FRC cannot return an object list with duplicate elements.

Comment: @MartinR I had thought about going the other way around: fetching all customers and getting their notifications. In that case I do not know if `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` methods would be executed if a  notification is modified.

Comment: No, a FRC on "customer" will not get notified of changes in related "notification" objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just fetch the customers with the FRC and set the `sectionNameKeyPath` to `nil`.

**Sections**
The number of returned results is your number of sections. Populate the section headers with the customer data.

**Rows**
The number of rows in section would be `customer.notifications.count`. To populate the row, make sure the `notifications` are sorted in some way (say, by date) and display them accordingly with something like this:

```
NSArray *orderedNotifications = 
  [customerForSection.notifications sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
   @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]]];
Notification *notificationToBeDisplayed = 
   [orderedNotifications objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

---

An alternative - recommended - solution is to change the data model. You could associate the notification with all customers directly. That would have the added advantage, that notifications remain associated with the correct customers even if group memberships change.

Comment: A customer is not directly associated with a notification but with many groups, so I cannot execute `customer.notifications.count`

Comment: Is a FRC useful here at all? The FRC will track changes to the "customer" objects, but not to the associated "notification" objects.

Comment: @elitalon Then it should be `customer.groups.notifications.count`. Same concept. But see my edit & additional solution.

Comment: @MartinR Any change to the object graph should be noted by the FRC and trigger its delegate methods.

Comment: @Mundi Per `NSFetchedResultsController` documentation it _notifies its delegate that the controller’s **fetch results** have been changed_. For me it's not clear that a change in a `Notification` propagates to all related `Group` and then to every realated `Customer`.

Comment: Good point. This probably warrants a test. However, the FRC has also memory management and performance advantages, apart from the delegate callbacks.